# Duplicate values in multiple textbox

Tags: asp.net, performance, duplicates

How to validate whether the text in multiple textboxes are unique from each other.

It looks like that in asp.net but its not a valid syntax

```
bool hasNoDuplicate = (txtEmergencyName1.Text.Trim() <> txtEmergencyName2.Text.Trim() <> txtEmergencyName3.Text.Trim <> txtEmergencyName4.Text.Trim);
```

I am looking for an efficient appraoch, kind of lambda expression or inbuilt in asp.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're asking for lambda, here's a linq approach.

```
var allTxt = new[] { txtEmergencyName1, txtEmergencyName2, txtEmergencyName3, txtEmergencyName4 };
var allText = allTxt.Select((txt, i) => new { Text = txt.Text.Trim(), Pos = i + 1 }).ToList();
bool hasNoDuplicate = !allText.Any(t => allText.Skip(t.Pos).Any(t2 => t.Text == t2.Text));
```

Put all relevant TextBoxes in a collection like an array and use `Enumerable.Any`. By skipping all before the current textbox you avoid checking the TextBoxes twice.

If all relevant `TextBoxes` are in a container control like a `Panel`, you could also use `Enumerable.OfType` to find them:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> allTxt = this.EmergencyPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

**Side-note:** it's premature optimization anyway to look for the most performant way to validate some controls. This is nothing what you are doing constantly and there are never millions of controls. Instead you should  look for the shortest or most readable approach.

Comment: although i am also thinking to put each element in array first, then iterate each one, can't it be possible by a **group **

Comment: It should be more efficient to do something like `var allTxt = new[] { txtEmergencyName1.Text.Trim(), etc..`.  Then you don't have to do a `.Text.Trim()` for each duplicate check.  And you would be working with just the strings, not the entire TextBoxes.  Since he asked about efficiency ...

Comment: @Halvard: Imho it's premature optimization anyway to ask for the most performant way to validate some controls. This is nothing what you are doing constantly and there are never millions of controls. However, i've edited my answer to provide a more efficient approach.

Comment: @ManishRawat: What do you mean? I've already provided a way to avoid an array at all if you   put all controls in a container control like `Panel`.

Comment: List<string> lst = new List<string>() { txtEmergencyName1.Text.Trim(), txtEmergencyName2.Text.Trim(), txtEmergencyName3.Text.Trim(), txtEmergencyName4.Text.Trim() };
                bool hasNoDuplicate = lst.TrueForAll(x => lst.Count(y => y == x) == 1);

Comment: @ManishRawat: Interesting, although it's not as efficient than the `Any`. The `TrueForAll` checks all and compares with all. The `Any` will break as soon as it has found a duplicate, it also will not compare things twice as the `TrueForAll` (`TextBox1` will be compared with `TextBox2` **and vice-versa**).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thankx for advicing Any over TrueForAll although I didn't understand the reason but Any is anyways great.. hehe..

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree with your side note.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and &&` or `or ||` operator accordingly

```
bool isDuplicate=(txtEmergencyName1.Text.Trim() == txtEmergencyName2.Text.Trim() 
                       && txtEmergencyName2.Text.Trim() == txtEmergencyName3.Text.Trim);
```

it will set `true` or `false` in the isDuplicate variable.

### Edit 1

```
     bool isDuplicate=(txtEmergencyName1.Text.Trim() == txtEmergencyName2.Text.Trim() 
                       && txtEmergencyName2.Text.Trim() == txtEmergencyName3.Text.Trim
                       && txtEmergencyName1.Text.Trim() == txtEmergencyName3.Text.Trim
                     );
```

Comment: its wrong, 
t1=1
t2=2
t3=1

So your condition is 
1==2 && 2==1 which is false always but it has duplicate entries of t1 and t3.

Comment: @ManishRawat ok I understand the problem now.

Comment: and suppose there are more textboxes, then it doesn't look a good approach

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like

```
        var test = new TextBox();
        var AlltBox = new List<TextBox>() { new TextBox() };

        for(int i=1; i == 5;i++)
        AlltBox.Add((TextBox)this.FindName("txtEmergencyName"+i));

        bool exist = AlltBox.Any(tb => ((tb.Text == test.Text)&& tb.Name != test.Name));
```

but i don't know about the performance